# perl multiple forms problem

Tags: perl, forms

Hy guys! My first time developing an Perl web application.
I have a page with 2 forms , on submit each going on separate other pages.
The problem is as follows:
When submiting the second form it goes on the first form action.
Params are send through Get method and the url contains the input string from both forms.
Here is the code.

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl

use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
 print "content-type: text/html \n\n";
 print '<html>';
 print '<body>';
# DBI CONFIG VARIABLES
$host = "localhost";
$database = "t2";
$port = 3308;
$user = "";
$pw = "";


#DATA SOURCE NAME
$dsn = "dbi:mysql:$database:localhost:3306";

# PERL DBI CONNECT (RENAMED HANDLE)
$conn = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw) or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";

$query = 'SELECT * From book';

$query_handle = $conn->prepare($query);

# EXECUTE THE QUERY
$query_handle->execute();

$query_handle->bind_columns(\$id, \$title ,\$author ,\$price, \$stock);

print '<table border="1">';
print '<thead>';
print '<tr>';
print '<td> Id </td>';
print '<td> title</td>';
print '<td> Author </td>';
print '<td> price</td>';
print '<td> Stock </td>';
print '<td> Buy </td>';

print '</tr>';
print '</thead>';

while($query_handle->fetch()) {



    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>';
    print $id;
    print '<td\>';
    print '<td>';
    print $title;
    print '<td\>';
    print '<td>';
    print $author;
    print '<td\>';
    print '<td>';
    print $price;
    print '<td\>';
    print '<td>';
    print $stock;
    print '<td\>';
    print '<td>';
    if ($stock ne '0') 
    {

        print '<form name="form1" action = "http://localhost/t3/buyBook.pl" method="get">';
        print '<input type="hidden" name="buy_id" value="'.$id.'"';
        print '<input type="submit"  name="buy"  value="Buy"';
        print '<form\>'
    }else
    {
        print '<input type="submit" name="buy" disabled="disabled" value="Buy"';
    }
    print '<td\>';
    print '<tr\>';

} 
print '</table>';

print '<form name="form2" action="http://localhost/t3/search_book.pl" method="get   ">';
print '<br/>';
print 'Search for book by:';
print '<br/>';
print '<input type="radio" name="searchBy" value="Title"> Title <br/>';
print '<input type="radio" name="searchBy" value="Author"> Author <br/>';
print '<input type="text" name="search_book" >';
print '<br/>';
print '<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">';
print '</form>';

print '<body/>';
print '<html/>';
```

Here is the  url shown when pressing any of the 2 submit buttons:
http://localhost/tema3/buyBook.pl?buy_id=7505&buy_id=2&buy_id=12195&search_book=&search=Search

Any idea how to fix this?
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we problem here is that you're closing tags incorrectly. This causing first `<form>` to "grab" all parameters below it. Try to fix with following:

```
print '</form>'; ## this is correct closing tag for a form
```

`</form>` and `<form\>` are not the same things. `<form\>` will open new form instead of closing. In fact it'll not do anything, because nested forms are not allowed.

You should also use `</td>` and `</tr>` tags at the end of table cell and row.

Comment: Also please add `use strict;` at the begging of the script. It'll make your live much easier. You'll need to declare new variables with `my`. But it'll also reduce chance of mistype in name of the variable.